# C#: How to structure this method that is meant to be overridden

Tags: c#, oop, error-handling, overriding, abstract-class

So, I have the method below, which is part of an `abstract` class that is basically a 2d array of characters. I intend to have several subclasses with slightly different behavior, that know how to populate themselves in different ways.

The method in question is supposed to insert a string into the array. To avoid overflow errors, I need to check if there is room in the array. Checking whether this is enough room is simple enough, but that is where the problem begins.

If there isn't enough room, I want each subclass to define how it will handle that behavior. (E.g., some subclasses will just start over at the beginning, others will do nothing and stop inserting characters, others will erase the top line, move everything up, and write it on the new blank line on the bottom, others will just give up and crash the program, etc.)

See the comments in the below code. I think I want to `override` the implementation, but is there a way I can just override the else branch, or do I have to move the whole method into the subclass?

(`IsEnoughRoom` is a private method within the class.)

```
internal void InsertString(string stringToInsert, int xStart, int yStart)
{
    char[] charsToInsert = stringToInsert.ToCharArray();
    int currentXPosition = xStart;
    int currentYPosition = yStart;

    // For each character in the array of charsToInsert,
    for (int i = 0; i < charsToInsert.Length; i++)
    {
        // Check if there is enough room...
        if(isEnoughRoom(xStart, yStart, charsToInsert))
        {
            SetCharAt(currentXPosition, currentYPosition, charsToInsert[i]);

            if (currentXPosition < xSize - 1)
            {
                currentXPosition++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentXPosition = 0;
                currentYPosition++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: What do we do if there isn't enough room?
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call a virtual or abstract method in the `else` branch? It's not clear how you'd "start over at the beginning" mind you... my guess is that you can't *really* express everything you'd want to do within the else branch...

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct me if I'm wrong, but I wouldn't be able to access the fields within the method if I did that, would I? By that I mean, I wouldn't be able to, for example, set `currentYPosition` to `0` and start over at the beginning? Or am I missing a concept here?

Comment: Well you *could* potentially pass the variables by reference to the method... or use the return value. (Or you might want to encapsulate all of those into a single object...) But that's where it would have been so helpful to show what the body of that `else` branch would look like in the different cases...

Comment: @JonSkeet By start over at the beginning, I mean to begin writing the remainder of the string at the [0,0] position in the array.

Comment: Right, so that just sounds like you may want to pass the x and y values by reference.

Comment: Actually, I walked away, ate lunch, and reread your comments and I now understand what you are saying. Who knew. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possible alternate approach where your abstract class' method is `virtual`, and it can return an enumeration value to determine what was the result and let the caller do the rest. The whole caller can be a derived class.

Let's see this solution in action:

```
public enum CharInsertionResult
{
    Success,
    NoRoom
}

public abstract class CharInserter
{
    internal virtual CharInsertionResult InsertString(string stringToInsert, int xStart, int yStart)
    {
        char[] charsToInsert = stringToInsert.ToCharArray();
        int currentXPosition = xStart;
        int currentYPosition = yStart;

        // For each character in the array of charsToInsert,
        for (int i = 0; i < charsToInsert.Length; i++)
        {
            // Check if there is enough room...
            if(isEnoughRoom(xStart, yStart, charsToInsert))
            {
                SetCharAt(currentXPosition, currentYPosition, charsToInsert[i]);

                if (currentXPosition < xSize - 1)
                {
                    currentXPosition++;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentXPosition = 0;
                    currentYPosition++;
                }

                return CharInsertionResult.Success
            }
            else
            {
                return CharInsertionResult.NoRoom;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now a derived class can override abstract class' implementation to provide a solution to `CharInsertionResult.NoRoom` case:

```
public class SpecializedCharInserter : CharInserter
{
     internal override CharInsertionResult InsertString(string stringToInsert, int xStart, int yStart)
     {
            CharInsertionResult result = base.InsertString(stringToInsert, xStart, yStart);

            switch(result)
            {
                 case CharInsertionResult.NoRoom:
                      // Do stuff here to handle this scenario
                      break;

                 default:
                      return result;
            }
     }
}
```

IMHO, I believe that it's a good design because if you don't want to handle `NoRoom` scenario you don't need to override a method, otherwise, you've an extensibility point to do so in a derived class.

Comment: But I can only subclass one class at a time, and the class containing InsertString has other methods needed to fulfill its responsibility that would be out of place in a CharInserter class. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans If a given subclass needs these methods, then you need to make them `protected`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I reread your answer and understand it better now. Turns out I just needed to walk away from the laptop for a minute and think about something else before coming back to it. Now that I know what you mean, I think this is a good way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans You're welcome! Yeah, sometimes you need to go away from the problem to solve it!